# winforms application guidelines

Tags: winforms, menu

I want to start creating an application that has a menu on the left(some items in a tree) and I want to open different pages on the right on the form when I click these items. Could anybody guide me in doing this correctly pls? I dont want to have tons of data in memory and just display these pages one in top of another.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of data are we talking about?  What would be in the pages?  Where is this data coming from?  If you don't want to load the data up from for all pages then where are you planning on persisiting the data and/or where is the data coming from (Application, Database, XML)

Comment: What do you mean by tons? Do you have any figures on this?

Comment: There will be different data from one or more databases. The controls will be loaded with all this data. 
"Tons" means megs of RAM, so that I dont want to keep 60 forms(with data) in memory just for the time they will be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to have treeview [docked](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6165908.html) on the left and a panel docked to fill. Then, on the [SelectedNodeChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.selectednodechanged.aspx) event of the tree, you can load forms into the panel. Just be sure to clear out the old form every time you change nodes.

By pages, do you mean web pages? If so, take a look at the [WebBrowser](http://frazzleddad.blogspot.com/2007/07/working-with-webbrowser-control-in.html) control.

Comment: I'm specially interested in this one: "Just be sure to clear out the old form every time you change nodes."

Comment: panel1.controls.clear(), otherwise you'll end up with a stack of forms inside the panel